# ¿Cómo puedo paginar mis resultados?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un sitio que me carga una lista de clientes, y actualmente son poco mas de 8400 clientes, entonces al querer cargar el listado, se esta demorando demasiado, quisiera que alguien por favor me guié o me ayude en que podria hacer, se que puedo paginar, pero no se exactamente que debo hacer para que se carguen de a poco los resultados.

Aqui comparto el codigo de la funcion que se utiliza para cargar los clientes, si alguien me ayuda como seria mas o menos paginando lo agradeceria mucho ya que no se que mas hacer.

```
public function getClientes($detailed = false) {
    $response = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes where estado = '" . ESTADO_ACTIVO . "' or estado = '" . ESTADO_PENDIENTE . "' order by apellido, nombre LIMIT 100");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $res = array(
            'id_cliente' => $row['id_cliente'],
            'cedula' => $row['cedula'],
            'nombre' => utf8_encode($row['nombre']),
            'apellido' => utf8_encode($row['apellido']),
            'sector' => utf8_encode($row['sector']),
            'direccion' => utf8_encode($row['direccion']),
            'correo' => $row['correo'],
            'instagram' => $row['instagram'],
            'nacimiento' => $row['nacimiento'],
            'celular' => $row['celular'],
            'imagen' => $row['imagen'],
        );
        if ($detailed) {
            $res["comentarios"] = $this->getComentariosByCliente($row["id_cliente"]);
            $res["servicios"] = $this->getServiciosByCliente($row["id_cliente"]);
            $res["premios"] = $this->getPremiosByCliente($row["id_cliente"]);
            $res["puntos_totales"] = 0;
            foreach ($res["servicios"] as $key => $servicio) {
                $res["puntos_totales"] += $servicio["puntos"];
            }
            $res["puntos_restantes"] = $res["puntos_totales"];
            foreach ($res["premios"] as $key => $premio) {
                $res["puntos_restantes"] -= $premio["puntos"];
            }
        }
        $response[] = $res;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Quería usar otro estilo pero no, me dicen que debo usar el que ya esta que es este, aquí puse para que muestre unicamente 10 resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y realmente no sé como adaptarlo para que funcione con un paginado en el mysql, aquí comparto el código que llena esta tabla, para que por favor me ayuden con como podría hacerlo.

```
$.get('../api/v1/clientes/all', {}, function(returnedData) {
  if(returnedData["error"] == false) {
     clientes = returnedData["clientes"];
     clientes.forEach(function(data) {

        $("#tableClientes").append("<tr><td>"+data['nombre'] + " " + data['apellido'] + "</td><td>" + data['correo'] + "</td><td>" + data['cedula'] + "</td><td>" + data['puntos_totales'] + "</td><td>" + data['puntos_restantes'] + "</td><td><a onclick='showComentarios(" + '"' + data["id_cliente"] + '"' + ")' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Comentarios'><i class='icon-envelope' style='color:white;'></i></a><a href='clientes-form.php?id=" + data["id_cliente"] + "' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Editar'><i class='icon-pencil' style='color:white;'></i></a><a onclick='borrarRegistro(\"clientes\"," + '"' + data['id_cliente'] + '"' + ")' class='btn btn-accion btn-circle asignar' title='Eliminar'><i class='icon-trash' style='color:white;'></i></a></td></tr>");
     });
     $("#table").DataTable({"pageLength": 50});
 }
```

}

Comment: Hola, ¿tu solución está bien agregando un botón de siguiente y anterior para navegar entre páginas?

Comment: La [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/320350/154302) brindada por [Vlady](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/154383/vlady) cubre la parte del backend de tu aplicacion, para la parte visual puedes usar por ejemplo [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/). La paginacion de bootstrap es facil de modificar y se ve asi: ![paginacion bootstrap(https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/154383/vlady)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0neD.png)

Comment: Si pero son de un datatable de js

Comment: Una forma sencilla de paginación (ya sea a nivel de la base de datos, trayendo solo lo necesario) o a nivel de la interfaz (paginando a nivel de html) es utlizar jquery datatables.
Muy recomendable UI que realmente se adepta a todo tipo de grillas y paginados.
Pruébalo a ver que te parece!! Si precisas una mano con eso a las órdenes.

Answer (score 4):

Debes incluir sentencias de paginación en tu SQL:

*MySQL/MariaDB*

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
LIMIT 1,10
```

*Postgres*

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

En ambos casos obtendrá los primeros 10 registros, para los siguientes 10 registros las últimas líneas cambian a:

*MySQL/MariaDB*

```
LIMIT 11,10
```

*Postgres*

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Para tu caso y hacerlo paramétrico, el código de tu SQL cambiaría a algo parecido a esto (si es Postgres cambiar con lo explicado arriba):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes where estado = '" . ESTADO_ACTIVO . "' or estado = '" . ESTADO_PENDIENTE . "' order by apellido, nombre LIMIT " . $desde . "," . $total);
```

Donde las variables **$desde** y **$total** puedes obtenerlo desde la vista creando botones de paginación.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar y luego cuento :)

Comment: Yo a esto le añadiría que, si crece la cantidad de registros, esta estrategia de paginación se hace más lenta a medida que se avanza entre páginas. Sin embargo, es un comienzo y cubre la necesidad actual. Supongo.

Comment: @Juan94 si estás usando una librería en frontend deberías revisar la documentación de esa librería, por lo general te brindan guías para hacer las llamadas ajax incluyendo los parámetros que envían y la forma de respuesta que esperan. Si estás haciendo tu propio código frontend, asegúrate de enviar los parámetros de paginación al backend. Por lo general también necesitarías hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla` para saber el total de registros que tienes.